# XPath: Assessing an Error in this Line of Code?

Tags: python, xpath, finance, stock

I recently began learning XPath for a Python project, but I can't seem to get the following line selecting the correct piece of data.

```
//table[@id="yfncsumtab"]//tr/td/a[@rel="first"]
```

---

Said data is found on this page:http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=QQQX+Historical+Prices

(Inspect Element the "Next" link to get to the code I'm attempting to create an XPath to.  In other words, Command/Control F on that page, and Inspect Element the first result)

I've tried many variations of that code, but none seem to select the proper text.  I appreciate any and all help - thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is that element?

Comment: How do you get to the page? I get "Hmmm... the page you're looking for isn't here. Try searching above." (not in USA)

Comment: If you "Inspect Element" the "Next" link, you should be brought right to it.

Comment: Re-did the link.  Working now? @elyase

Comment: No.  What does `"Inspect Element" the "Next" link` mean?, and what does that have to do `rel='first'`?

Comment: It's alright now, but thanks for looking into my measly problem anyways!  But for the sake of answering your question, "Inspect Element" the "Next" link means to right-click on the link that reads "Next" (found on that page provided) and press "Inspect Element".  Rel='first' can be found in the website code.

Comment: But what does rel='first' have to do with the Next link???

Comment: Whoops, sorry, it was: 'code'<a rel="next" href="/q/hp?s=QQQX&amp;d=11&amp;e=28&amp;f=2014&amp;g=d&amp;a=1&amp;b=1&amp;c=2007&amp;z=66&amp;y=66" data-rapid_p="21" class="">Next</a> 'code'  rel"next", not first.  That must have been part of my error.

Comment: Thank you kind sir! :-)  I wish you the best of luck as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'//a[text()="Next"]'
```

or:

```
'//table[@id = "yfncsumtab"]//a[text()="Next"]'
```

or, to get just the first one:

```
'//table[@id = "yfncsumtab"]//table[1]/tr/td/a[text()="Next"]'
```

or:

```
'//table[@id="yfncsumtab"]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tr/td/a[1]'
```

The more specific you are, the faster it is to find the element.  However, the more specific you are, the more *brittle* the xpath is: if the developers make a small change in the html structure surrounding the target element, your code won't work.

```
from lxml import html

doc = html.parse("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=QQQX+Historical+Prices")

my_xpath = '//a[text()="Next"]'

for element in doc.xpath(my_xpath):
    print("<{}>".format(element.tag))
    print("  text = {}".format(element.text))

    for attr, val in element.items():
        print("  {} = {}".format(attr, val))


--output:--
<a>
  text = Next
  rel = next
  href = /q/hp?s=QQQX&d=11&e=28&f=2014&g=d&a=1&b=1&c=2007&z=66&y=66
<a>
  text = Next
  rel = next
  href = /q/hp?s=QQQX&d=11&e=28&f=2014&g=d&a=1&b=1&c=2007&z=66&y=66
```

Comment: Thank you - it feels as if you read my mind!  For the last few moments, I've been pondering how I should pursue my next goal: getting the 'href' printed - but you just provided me (and the rest of the world) with a great response on how to do so, and more!  Again, thanks! :-)  (wish I could up vote, need to wait 'till 15 rep)

Comment: @TheNovice, You don't have to loop through all the attributes to get the href: `element.get('href')` works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
//*[(@id = "yfncsumtab")]//a[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 3) and parent::*)]
```

With this Xpath I get both the top and the bottom 'Next' link.

Comment: Thanks! I currently have that selector gadget, but the XPath it provides (for this example) is just "//a", which is a bit too broad. Do you happen to know of anything (for the future) that can provide an answer that's bit more specific? (Also: Five whole minutes until I can best-answer! C'mon...)

Comment: Chrome Inspector and then copy XPath. But not always works. I think Firebug does this also but I have never tried it. I mostly use pyquery and CSS selectors because I worked in web design.

Comment: Yup, tried that as well.  Guess the most reliable way is to learn XPath.  Thanks again for your help - much appreciated!